# View which isn't affected by UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I need a view which is still on the same position when I scroll a `UIScrollView`. But this view has to be in the bounds of the scroll view. Are there any solutions to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a **superview** which has the same frame as the scroll view and make the scroll view and your new view its **subview**.

[image: layout sctructure]

Comment: yeah but how do i get one view in the foreground of this two?

Answer (score 1):

Just place this view not inside `UIScrollView`, but inside superview of the `UIScrollView`.